# Webpack generating SCSS source maps but not JS

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular9

I have reproduced my issue at https://github.com/franklin626/custom_webpack_undebuggable.

Starting with a standard Angular 9 CLI application, I had a need to customize the webpack build so that my SCSS files can import JSON configs. This means, in `angular.json`, moving from

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"
```

to

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "webpack.config.js"
        }
       ...
```

With `webpack.config.js` containing the following:

```
const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
            options: {
              implementation: require('node-sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                precision: 8,
                importer: jsonImporter(),
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I am only getting the source maps for the css, but not for the javascript. And yes, my Chrome has JS and CSS maps enabled. Not sure what is going on here ?

`angular.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-web-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.deploy.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/my-web-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "webpack.config.js",
              "sourceMap": true
            },
            "browserTarget": "my-web-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-web-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-web-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "webpack.config.js"
            },
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["tsconfig.app.json", "tsconfig.spec.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:protractor",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "webpack.config.js"
            },
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-web-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-web-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-web-app"
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "doc": "node src/scripts/runMarked.js",
    "prestart": "npm run doc",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.4",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@types/vega": "^3.2.0",
    "build": "^0.1.4",
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.5",
    "marked": "^0.8.0",
    "msal": "^1.2.2-beta.0",
    "ng": "0.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "vega": "^5.9.1",
    "vega-embed": "^6.2.2",
    "vega-lite": "^4.4.0",
    "vega-typings": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.3.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "node-sass-json-importer": "^4.1.2",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about js or css source maps?

Comment: @nickbullock it's js I am after.

Comment: I've added a github repo that minimally replicates my setup and issue. Upon `ng serve`, you'll see in the developer tools that only original .scss are served. All the typescript is missing. https://github.com/franklin626/custom_webpack_undebuggable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest I can't reproduce your issue with sourcemaps (I mean js sourcemaps, maybe you turned them off in browser? I usually turn js source maps off in angular applications to debug ngfactories and etc), but I almost sure that you got into conflicting webpack rules problem.

Please change your custom webpack config to the following to understand the problem:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');

module.exports = function (defaultConfig) {

  console.log('>>>>> debug default config rules', defaultConfig.module.rules);

  const config = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
              options: {
                implementation: require('node-sass'),
                sassOptions: {
                  // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                  precision: 8,
                  importer: jsonImporter(),
                  outputStyle: 'expanded'
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return merge(defaultConfig, config);
}
```

In this log you will see that default anguar config already have two rules for `/\.scss$|\.sass$/`.
First one for component or directive styles (`component.scss`):

```
  {
    exclude: [
      '/Users/nikitabalakirev/Desktop/Projects/angular-webpack-custom-sass-rule-example/src/styles.scss'
    ],
    test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
    use: [ ... ]
  },
```

And the second for global styles:

```
  {
    include: [
      '/Users/nikitabalakirev/Desktop/Projects/angular-webpack-custom-sass-rule-example/src/styles.scss'
    ],
    test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
    use: [
      ...
    ]
  },
```

This means that your rule and default rules overlapping each other and that can lead to unexpected behavior.
What you can do with this information:

1. If you need `scss` files to be able to import json files you need to change existing default rule, not to add your own, something like that:

```
const myRule =    {
              loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
              options: {
                implementation: require('node-sass'),
                sassOptions: {
                  // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                  precision: 8,
                  importer: jsonImporter(),
                  outputStyle: 'expanded'
                }
              }
            }
const scssComponentRule = defaultConfig.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test.toString().includes('scsss'));
scssComponentRule.use.unshift(myRule);
```

2. If you need NOT ALL of your scss files to be able to load jsons, use special "domain" name for such files:
   `test: /\.special\.scss$|\.sass$/,` and file name for example `styles.special.scss`, but you still need to exclude them from Angular's rules!
3. If you don't need Angular's rules you can remove them from default config. But from my experience it's a huge page to support angular application with custom styling rules. It can crash after each update.

Tip: you can find and research angular default config [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs)

Also please make sure that your `angular.json` looks like this:

```
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
```

and

```
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-webpack-custom-sass-rule-example:build"
          },
```

**UPD**
I opened a [pr](https://github.com/franklin626/custom_webpack_undebuggable/pull/1) in your repo, thanks for the easy reproduction.
As I said previously it is about default and custom config conflicts.
Angular uses `SourceMapDevToolPlugin` for source maps so you don't need to set `devtool` property, just leave it blank.

Comment: Thanks you. I've looked carefully into your answer and replicated it, I don't think I have an issue that is directly linked to this additional SCSS rule I have. I seems to be just due to the fact I am having lazy loaded modules AND use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server` instead of the default. I automatically get minified/bundled code upon `ng serve`.... It's annoying.

Comment: Where can I see the `console.log` output ?

Comment: in your terminal after running ng serve

Comment: can you please describe/show how do you load lazy modules and share your package.json and angular.json?

Comment: I thought so, but I couldn't find anything of interest upon `ng serve` :o

Comment: added angular.json and package.json

Answer (score 2):

Here is working the `webpack` and `angular.json` configurations:

#### angular.json

```
{
  ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser", // <---
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./webpack.config.js", // <---
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server", // <---
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "test:build" // <---
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
const jsonImporter = require("node-sass-json-importer");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve("sass-loader"),
            options: {
              implementation: require("node-sass"),
              sassOptions: {
                // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                precision: 8,
                importer: jsonImporter(),
                outputStyle: "expanded",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

`ng serve/build/build --prod` work. And I got this result (changed colors as in your json file)
[image]

In general, the past answer looks correct. But something wrong with the merging of default and custom webpack configs. `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` merges configs itself if the custom webpack config returns an object. If it returns a function then this function should merge them itself. And maybe this merging produced and issue.